# Get the width of Chinese strings correctly

Tags: string, go, terminal, rune

I want to make a border around the text `这是一个测试`, but I cannot get the actual width of it. With English text, it does work perfectly.

[image: Screenshot]

#### Here is my analysis:

`len` tells me this:

```
这是一个测试 18
aaaaaaaaa 10
つのだ☆HIRO 16
aaaaaaaaaa 10
```

runewidth.StringWidth tells me this:

```
这是一个测试 12
aaaaaaaaa 10
つのだ☆HIRO 11
aaaaaaaaaa 10
```

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println("这是一个测试 |")
    fmt.Println("aaaaaaaaaa | 10*a")
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("这是一个测试 |")
    fmt.Println("aaaaaaaaa | 9*a")
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("Both are not equal to the Chinese text.")
    fmt.Println("The (pipe) lines are not under each other.")
}
```

[image]

#### Question:

How can I get my box (first screenshot) to appear correctly?

Comment: Yes, this gives me the actual rune count, but some runes have different width (visually) and thus the box has an offset in the border

Comment: What is `runewidth`?

Comment: https://github.com/mattn/go-runewidth This library is supposed to fix those problems, and most of the time it does work as intendet. But in the string from above, we have narrow and wide characters.

Comment: @MarvinJWendt runes do not have a "pixel width", the font does. Therefore the answer will depend on the tool/package you're using to render the font.

Comment: In the 2 lines of "aaa..." the first line has only 9 `a`, the length of it differ from second line clearly, how did you get the length result?

Comment: @rustyhu yes, that's right. If you add an "a" tho, it will be wider than the Chinese text. I need to make them the same width somehow, but I don't get how to do it, as I don't have experience with letters that have a different width.

Comment: Maybe you need [`golang.org/x/text`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text); in particular, its `width` subpackage.

Comment: @mkopriva I think I somehow need to add a "half-width" character to the Chinese string to make it level. But I am really lost on how to do that.

Comment: @kostix yeah I also tried that. It just gives me the length of a single rune, and sadly I didn't get it to work with my problem.

Comment: So, iterating over all the runes in a string and combining their widths does not cut it, right?

Comment: @kostix sadly not. I think this is also what runewidth does (by mattn). I think the chinese text has some "half-width" runes, so with normal text like "a" I am either below or above the width of the Chinese text. I can never make them the same width. So I guess that I would have to automatically insert a blank rune, which makes the total width round again. The chinese text might look like this: "1 1 0.5 1 1" and with "normal" letters I would only get "1 1 1 1 1" or "1 1 1 1" which are both wrong. I would need to somehow modify the Chinese text to be: "1 1 0.5 1 1 (0.5)". Just speculating tho..

Comment: You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mkopriva added one to the end :)

Comment: I would suggest posting a message to [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) which is frequented by the devs (and Mattn). (If you do so, please post the link to the message here as a comment.)

Comment: https://imgur.com/OICYv8v note that on my setup each of those specific chinese characters is twice the width of a normal latin character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unicode](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode) characters (like Chinese characters) in Golang take 3 bytes, while ASCII only takes 1 byte. That's by design.

If you wish to check the actual string size of unicode character, use [unicode/utf8](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8) built-in package.

```golang
fmt.Printf("String: %s\nLength: %d\nRune Length: %d\n", c, len(c), utf8.RuneCountInString(c))
// String: 这是一个测试
// Length: 18
// Rune Length: 6
```

More basic way to count is by using for loop.

```golang
count := 0
for range "这是一个测试" {
    count++
}
fmt.Printf("Count=%d\n", count)
// Count=6
```

About the pretty print of Chinese and English strings in tabular format, there seems to be no direct way. Nor the tabwriter works in this case. A small hack-around this is to use csv writer as follows:

```golang
data := [][]string{
    {"这是一个测试", "|"},
    {"aaaaaaaaaa", "|"},
    {"つのだ☆HIRO", "|"},
    {"aaaaaaaaaa", "|"},
}

w := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
defer w.Flush()
w.Comma = '\t'

for _, row := range data {
    w.Write(row)
}
```

This should print data as expected. Unfortunately, StackOverflow isn't printing the same format as I see in terminal. But Playground to our rescue. [Click Here](https://play.golang.org/p/032QNfU7nbe)

`Note`: This works for strings with rune size close enough to one another. For lengthier strings, you'd need more work-around.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is (as [mkopriva points out in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69559133/get-the-width-of-chinese-strings-correctly#comment122948839_69559133)) a *display* issue, not amenable to being resolved by any sort of counting trick.

We have the same problem when we display variable-pitch, or proportional, text, vs [monospace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) text, in English.  That is, compare:

```
mmmm, tasty
iiii, tasty?
```

with:

mmmm, tasty
    iiii, tasty?

(assuming you use a browser to read this answer!).  We don't have to print Chinese characters, or even leave simple ASCII to have the problem!

What you need is a monospaced *display font* for your Chinese text, or perhaps some software to typeset it in tabular form, and how you get that is ... another question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want

```golang
func TestChinese(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []string{
        "这是一个测试",
        "aaaaaaaaa",
        "つのだ☆HIRO",
        "aaaaaaaaaa",
        "这是aaaaa一个测试",
        "这是一个つの测试",
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        fmt.Printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n", tt, len([]rune(tt)), len([]byte(tt)))
    }
}
```

output:

```sh
这是一个测试  6   18
aaaaaaaaa   9   9
つのだ☆HIRO    8   16
aaaaaaaaaa  10  10
这是aaaaa一个测试 11  23
这是一个つの测试    8   24
```